# woocommerce cross sell is only showing two random products on cart page

Tags: php, wordpress, woocommerce, hook-woocommerce

This is my code on cart page to show the cross-sell products, but the 
problem is that this is showing only two random products. I want to show 
more that two products.

I want to show all cross and upsell of the products that are currently in cart.

This is the code:

```
echo woocommerce_cross_sell_display();
```

Comment: For upsells you will have to use: **[`woocommerce_upsell_display()`**](https://docs.woocommerce.com/wc-apidocs/function-woocommerce_upsell_display.html) … For both you will need to build a custom function with a custom query.

Answer (score 2):

To display all the cross sells product, you can use the `woocommerce_cross_sells_total` filter with this code:

```
add_filter('woocommerce_cross_sells_total', 'cross_sells_limit');
function cross_sells_limit() {
    return -1;
}
```

For the up sells product, you just have to use the `woocommerce_upsell_display` function with no number of product limit already.